# Why is it not working? jQuery shortcut

Tags: jquery

```
$winders = $(window);  $josia = $(".josianne");

$winders.scroll( 

    function( )
    {
        var scrolledFromtop = $winders.scrollTop();

        if( scrolledFromtop > 300 )
        {
            $josia.text("LOWBWNOW");  // change it to $(".josianne")
        }
        else
        {
            $josia.text("DOZO, NAT, SARA"); // change it to $(".josianne")
        }
    }

);
```

The above does not work. However, if I change $josia to $(".josianne") it works

There is not a fatal syntax error but I am just wondering why $josia does not work

Comment: Did you wrap it in $(function(){ ... }) ? This will make sure the code runs after window+jquery is loaded. Maybe `.josianne` is defined later

Comment: @galchen Thanks a lot you gave me the perfect answer.  By the way, I remember reading there are three variables which mean the same thing.  Could you tell me what they are?  One of them was $(document) Thanks a lot

Comment: You mean `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` and `$(function(){ ... });`
The latter is more common. Also, some use `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)`